# Starting an ActiveMQ BrokerService on a remote machine

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to start a `BrokerService` on a remote machine in the network instead. 
Instead of having

```java
BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
```

I want to have:

```java
BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(tcp://remoteMachine:61616)"));
```

So essentially I have an application that should do everything remotely. It should start an ActiveMQ `BrokerService` remotely from my code and then use that broker to send and receive messages. Once the application has done its job it should shut the `BrokerService` down.

I have tried the code above but it keeps on giving me a JVM binding exception:

```
Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://remoteMachine:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
```

I can see that port is not in use but still throws this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `BrokerFactory.createBroker()` actually does. It *can't* create a broker on a remote machine. It can *only* create a local broker. The URI which you pass to it simply provides the configuration for the local broker. The syntax for this URI is documented [here](https://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri).

Since you're passing the name of a remote machine when attempting to create a local broker the broker creation process fails because it can't bind a listener to that name. The name must be the name of the machine where you're executing the `createBroker()` method or, more generally, `localhost`.

ActiveMQ doesn't provide any way to start a broker on a remote server. However, this kind of functionality really isn't in the domain of a message broker. That's the kind of functionality that would be provided by the operating system itself. For example, in Linux you'd have a script that would SSH into a remote machine and execute a command (e.g. starting a message broker).

Comment: Ahh I see. Understood. So does activemq provide a way to start a broker on a remote server?